# Scope of category in observer

Tags: magento2, category, event-observer, scope

I grab category object from observer on event `catalog_controller_category_init_after`. Should I check it against store id? Or the fact that its loaded in controller first and then passed to event (and observer) makes it valid against the scope, as well as its data?

Answer (score 1):

I've searched in `module-catalog/Controller/Category/View.php` and I saw that the method `_initCategory()` loads the category from the current store `$category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());` and after that is dispatching your `catalog_controller_category_init_after` event. So, no worries. You don't need to check it against store id.

```
protected function _initCategory()
    {
        $categoryId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
        if (!$categoryId) {
            return false;
        }

        try {
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category')->canShow($category)) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->_catalogSession->setLastVisitedCategoryId($category->getId());
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('current_category', $category);
        try {
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'catalog_controller_category_init_after',
                ['category' => $category, 'controller_action' => $this]
            );
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->_objectManager->get('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface')->critical($e);
            return false;
        }

        return $category;
    }
```

Comment: can you mark the answer accordingly ? thx